# Evently events stop being triggered after page reload

Tags: javascript, couchdb, couchapp, evently

I have a couchapp based on evently. When I push the couchapp and start browsing it, it works fine. But as soon as I reload the page, the events stop being generated: in this case click events on an `a href`.

The most confusing thing about this is that this is occurring only for events happening in a certain div: the rest of the divs continue to generate the events normally.

To get the events from the problematic div again, I need to re-push the couchapp.

Comment: It's going to be impossible to know what the problem is without seeing code.

Comment: I understand. I was hoping to have hit a known issue with evently, one which could be handled with a standard recipe (I was hoping something on the lines "return true from your event handler"). It is a lot of work to isolate the code causing the problem to share it here: doing that will probably be enough to find the problem by myself.

Comment: I completely understand your situation as I've been in it myself for the better part of a week (totally different situation, but same deal with a problem that only happens in the middle of a huge pile of code :-(

Comment: I think I am narrowing down the problem: I think it has to do with dynamically generated content. The evently framework seems to have trouble with that (maybe related to the bind/live/delegate/on issue)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was related to dynamically generated content. There is a followup [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7982493/event-listeners-for-dynamic-content-in-evently)