# Event listeners for dynamic content in evently

Tags: javascript, couchdb, mustache, couchapp, evently

I am generating a dynamic html table. One of the columns in the table has a clickable image (`a href`). For testing, I have also created a static table, with similar structure as the dynamic table, in the same div.

I have defined a `selectors/a/click.js` event handler, which works fine for the links in the static table, but not in the dynamic table.

It seems that, since the table is dynamically generated, evently is not attaching any event handlers to it.

Could somebody suggest a workaround for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a workaround: use `live` instead of `bind` in the evently library:

```
cd vendor/couchapp/_attachments
cat jquery.evently.js  | sed -e 's!\.bind(!.live(!'
```

I'll try to push this upstream into evently.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you may lay your events in a following way:

```
table/<event>/selectors/a/click.js
```

(where  is event responsible for filling your dynamic table, for example `_changes`). This ensures that the events are being bound after table is generated.